# Get changing variables from Magento block in knockout js

Tags: magento2, knockoutjs

Want to pass entityId to the getInfo method:
This block.phtml is on the catalog page (list) that gets called per Item on the page and sends each entity id to the getInfo method. The getInfo method then calls a controller that returns the info. If I add entityId to the initialize method only the first / last value gets passed to the getInfo method...

**block.phtml**

```
<script type="text/x-magento-init">
    {
        "#custom-component": {
            "Magento_Ui/js/core/app": {
               "components": {
                    "customcomponent": {
                        "component": "ACME_KnockoutDemo/js/custom-component",
                        "template" : "ACME_KnockoutDemo/custom-component",
                        "entityId": "<?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $product->getId() ?>"
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
</script>
```

**custom-component.js**

```
define([
  'uiComponent',
  'ko',
  'mage/url',
  'mage/storage',
  ], function (Component, ko, urlBuilder,storage) {
        'use strict';
        return Component.extend({

            initialize: function () {
                this._super();
            },

            getInfo:function () {
                var serviceUrl = urlBuilder.build('acme/getinfo?id=' + #ENTITIYID);
                storage.post(
                  serviceUrl,
                 ''
             ).done(
                 function (response) {
                     var jsonObj = JSON.parse(response);
                     this.info = jsonObj.info;
                 }
             ).fail(
                 function (response) {

                 }
             );

            }

        });
    }
);
```

**custom-component.html**

```
<div data-bind="scope: getInfo()">
  <p data-bind="text: info"></p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For starters, you have defined the wrong scope in `custom-component.html` it should be the name of your component. Replace your code with following;

```
<div data-bind="scope: customcomponent">
  <p data-bind="text: info"></p>
</div>
```

you will have to define info variable as you're using strict mode and define it to be observable.

```
define([
  'uiComponent',
  'ko',
  'mage/url',
  'mage/storage',
  ], function (Component, ko, urlBuilder,storage) {
        'use strict';
        return Component.extend({
            defaults: {
             info: ko.observable()
            },
            initialize: function () {
                this._super();
            },

            getInfo:function () {
                var serviceUrl = urlBuilder.build('acme/getinfo?id=' + #ENTITIYID);
                storage.post(
                  serviceUrl,
                 ''
             ).done(
                 function (response) {
                     var jsonObj = JSON.parse(response);
                     this.info = jsonObj.info;
                 }
             ).fail(
                 function (response) {

                 }
             );

            }

        });
    }
);
```